# C# graphics - how not to show picture immediately on load

Tags: c#, graphics

I am new to c# graphics and don't quite understand how things work. I made a handler for the Paint event for my picture box that loads an image. Now every time i start the app, it loads the image. Is there a way to make it load the image on button click? I have a button on the form. When is the Paint event triggered and what am I doing wrong?

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
        }
```

Comment: The Paint is only triggered when repainting is necessary. A picturebox which doesn't contain an image, doesn't need to be repainted. Use the Paint only when you change the picturebox's content, (like moving sprites etc)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen you should almost never use the Paint event on a picturebox due to how the PictureBox interacts with the paint function. You should just use the Paint event of a `Panel` if you are looking for a blank canvas to subscribe `Paint` on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rarely ever subscribe to the Paint event on a PictureBox control. you should be doing `pictureBox1.Image = bmp;` inside your click event handler for your button instead.